# Prevent/delay Modal Dialog Box from closing using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, modal-dialog

I am trying to retrieve the page name of each page on a site. The steps are the following:

1. Click on the settings icon

   - a Modal Dialog Box appears (That is what I believe they are called?). The Dialog Box appears for three seconds before closing.
2. Click on "Rename Page"

   - A Popup- window appears with a text field (containing the page name). The popup also contains the buttons "Ok" and "Cancel
3. Retrieve the name in the text field
4. Press Ok
5. Go to the next page. Repeat stages 1-4

For some reason at stage 2, seemingly at random, I receive a TimeOutException error. I say at random, because the error occurs on sometimes on say, the 55th page and sometimes 130th page and so on. I believe it might be because the dialog box closes, before the Rename Page button has been clicked (Which is weird since 3 seconds should be ample time to click on the button.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or4Jv.png)

I am using the framework Spyder to write code in. When the TimeOutException occurs, if I run the code from Step 1. Everything works again without error. So for some reason, sometimes the error occurs and sometimes not.

The HTML code for the Settings Icon is the following:

```
<div 
id="_labsfluxbar_WAR_labsfluxbarportlet_showCurrentPageSettingsPopupButton" 
class="labs-fluxbar-portlet-current-page-settings-popup">
</div>
```

The HTML code for 'Rename Page'

```
<ul 
class="labs-fluxbar-portlet-page-menu-items">   
    <li class="labs-fluxbar-portlet-page-menu-item labs-fluxbar-portlet-page-menu-item-rename" title="Rename this page" 
onclick="_labsfluxbar_WAR_labsfluxbarportlet_renamePage('9398653')">    Rename page
</li>
```

The code in Python:

```
i = 0
while True:
    #Get page name
    # Step 1 - Click on Settings icon
    settings = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "_labsfluxbar_WAR_labsfluxbarportlet_showCurrentPageSettingsPopupButton"))) #Search for settings button
    settings.click() #click settings icon
    # Step 2 - Click on the "Rename Page" button
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='labs-fluxbar-portlet-current-page-settings-popup-content']//li[@title='Rename this page']"))).click() #Click on the Rename page element 
    # Step 3 - Retrieve page name from text field
    page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='popup_prompt']") 
    page_name = page.get_property("value") #Copy the name of page
    print(page_name)
    # Step 4 - Click ok to close PopUp window
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='popup_ok']").click() #Exit the popup window
    # Step 5- Go to the next page
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "_labsfluxbar_WAR_labsfluxbarportlet_pageDropdownList")))
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('_labsfluxbar_WAR_labsfluxbarportlet_pageDropdownList'))
    select.select_by_index(i)
    i += 1
```

The TimeOutExcpetion (sometimes) occurs after running the following line, however I don't get why?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='labs-fluxbar-portlet-current-page-settings-popup-content']//li[@title='Ange ett nytt namn för sidan']"))).click()
```

Does anyone have any suggestion what is occurring, or what could be done to prevent it?

Comment: you see the `Rename` page button in the failed screenshot? Also can you please post the error message here.

Comment: I fixed the failed screenshot. 

The error message is:
  File "/Users/usernamne/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassingly the issue was not due to the code.. It was because of a bad/slow internet connection.